# Electron App downloading file on https

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, multi-factor-authentication

I have an electron app that works great to download a file from `HTTP`, however I need it to download the file from an `HTTPS` site. The `HTTPS` site uses `MFA`, and I have this working in the app. It will prompt me to log in via `MFA`, and then any URL links I have listed in my app open up as and do not need `MFA` authentication until I log in again.

The issue I have is: when I use the code below to get an `HTTPS` file, it gives me a 401, even though I have previously logged in via `MFA`, and I can access this file when browsing the site trough my app. It's like the code below does not look at the current session state? Any ideas on how to do this

```
function downloadFile() {
    var httpreq = require('httpreq');
    httpreq.download('https://mywebsite.com/test.xlsx',
                         __dirname + '/test.xlsx',
                             function (err, progress) {
                                 if (err) return console.log(err);
                                 console.log(progress);
                             },
                                 function (err, res) {
                                     if (err) return console.log(err);
                                     console.log(res);
                                 });
}
```

Comment: What current session state? Where should the session be coming from?

Comment: So at the start of the app I make it so you are redirected to a webpage within the app, that gets you to log in via MFA.. however the code above does not seem to recognise that I am logged in... If I did an href link somewhere in my app to the file I want to download that works, but I need to be able to download the file behind the scenes.. I don't want the user to be prompted to download a file.